# JavaScript get all image files from folder and append their names to array

Tags: javascript, file, browser, load

I have this code:

```
function randombg(){
  var bigSize = [
    "url('images/1.jpg')",
    "url('images/2.jpg')",
    "url('images/3.jpg')",
    "url('images/4.jpeg')",
    "url('images/5.jpeg')",
    "url('images/6.jpeg')",
    "url('images/7.jpeg')",
    "url('images/8.jpeg')",
    "url('images/9.jpeg')",
    "url('images/10.jpeg')",
    "url('images/11.jpeg')",
    "url('images/12.jpeg')",
    "url('images/13.jpeg')",
    "url('images/14.jpeg')",
    "url('images/15.jpeg')",
    "url('images/16.jpeg')",
    "url('images/17.jpeg')",
    "url('images/18.jpeg')",
    "url('images/19.jpeg')",
    "url('images/20.jpeg')",
    "url('images/21.jpeg')",
    "url('images/22.jpeg')",
    "url('images/23.jpeg')"         
  ];

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * bigSize.length) + 0;
  document.getElementById("random").style.backgroundImage = bigSize[random];
  console.log('image loading function end');
}
```

which generates a random background picture. I have more than 100 high-resolution photos, and it would be masochism to rename them all and the add their names to an image array. 
So I'm searching for a solution (in code) that gets all the images from an image folder resource and adds their names to an array. I have both `.jpg` and `.jpeg` formats.

Comment: what are you running server-side to build that list? PHP, Node, ASP, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access local files using JavaScript (security reasons) unless you are using node.

A possible solution would be to use the [File API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) but you still need to give permission.